# Is there a way to parametrize mixin in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, mixins

Can I somehow mixin a class with parameterized constructor?

Something like this:

```
class RenderedWithTemplates {
   def templates = []

   RenderedWithTemplates(templates) { ... }

   ...

}

@Mixin(RenderedWithTemplates(show: "showAddress.gsp", add: "addAddress.gsp")
class Address { ... }
```

Comment: Did you try [this code](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Mixins#Mixins-ParamaterizedMixing)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mixin proposal from 2007 [0], but the GroovyDefaultMethods#mixin [1] method has no support for parameterized mixins and neither has @Mixin.

As far as I can tell from the code example above, you need to find a way to mixin GSP view information that is tied to your (domain) classes. An alternative (and slightly groovier ;)) approach for this case would be to implement `RenderedWithTemplates` as annotation with a single closure parameter holding the GSP view information:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface RenderedWithTemplates {
    Class value()
}

@RenderedWithTemplates({ [show: "showAddress.gsp", add: "addAddress.gsp"] }) 
class Address {}

// shows how to read the map with all the GSP infos

def templateInfo = Address.getAnnotation(RenderedWithTemplates)
def gspMap = templateInfo.value().newInstance(this, this).call()
```

[0] http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Mixins

[1] http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html